# IIS Smooth Streaming - Silverlight Video - Add Clickable Link At End

Tags: silverlight, iis, expression-blend

I have encoded some videos with the IIS Smooth Streaming Transform Manager. I've discovered the [Silverlight Media Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/documentation) allows me to add additional `<PlayListItem>` entries to string multiple videos together in the play-list, however at the end of the videos I'd like to show a clickable link - is this possible?

Basically I'd like to send users to a survey after they've watched the videos.

Comment: Project moved somewhere http://smf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SMF%20v2%20%22How%20To%22%20Documentation&referringTitle=Home and there are js examples ,you may do it by js maybe , or request a feature from project page http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/content/smf/howto/v2/examples/ConsumingSMFPlayerJavaScriptAPI/ConsumingSMFPlayerJavaScriptAPI.html

Comment: I found the "Adding support for MAST, VAST, & VPAID based advertising" word document on the documentation page (from above) and it describes the `PreRollAdvertisement` etc, however I can't seem to get them to work. Perhaps the videos encoded with IIS Transform Manager use an old version of the SMF and I'm not sure how to translate the XAML properties to embedded HTML properties (i.e. `<param name="initparams" value='playerSettings = 
                        <Playlist>...<Items>...<PlaylistItem>...`